# WeChat Immediately Closing Using SDK

Tags: android, wechat

I'm trying to send text to WeChat for sharing and it looks like WeChat loads but then immediately closes. The error code I'm getting in WXEntryActivity is -6, which doesn't seem to correspond to anything in the ErrCode enum.

My package name is the same that the app was registered under and I'm building with the signature also used to register the app. I'm stumped on where to go from here.

Here's what I see in the logcat (including some data from the BaseResp object):

```
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: check signature:...
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: pass
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessageAct: send mm message, intent=Intent { cmp=com.tencent.mm/.plugin.base.stub.WXEntryActivity (has extras) }
D/WXEntryActivity: onResp: errStr: null
D/WXEntryActivity: onResp: transaction: text1461027271082
D/WXEntryActivity: onResp: getType(): 2
D/WXEntryActivity: onResp: errCode: -6
```

And this is the code that gets called to send the request (I literally copied it from someone's test app that works):

```
WXTextObject textObj = new WXTextObject();
textObj.text = "TEST TEXT";

WXMediaMessage msg = new WXMediaMessage();
msg.mediaObject = textObj;
// msg.title = "Will be ignored";
msg.description = "TEST DESCRIPTION";

SendMessageToWX.Req req = new SendMessageToWX.Req();
req.transaction = buildTransaction("text");
req.message = msg;
req.scene =/* isTimelineCb.isChecked() ? endMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneTimeline :*/ SendMessageToWX.Req.WXSceneSession;
api.sendReq(req);
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? I have same problem too. I want your help for weChat Integration in android App.

Comment: Nope, I've since moved on from the project.